# Is there a way to change the name of a Safari app extension in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, safari-extension, xcode9.4, safari-app-extension

I have created a Safari app extension through an Xcode target that I want to change the name of. Initially, when creating the Xcode target, I simply called it "Safari Extension", thinking that I would be able to change it easily later. I thought changing it would be as easy as changing the "Bundle display name" in the `Info.plist` file in the target folder, as shown here:

[image]

However, I tried this and built the app, but nothing changed. I also tried uninstalling and reinstalling the extension and even the entire app, to no avail. If anyone has a way to rename the Safari app extension, please let me know. Thanks so much!

Comment: Changing the bundle display name should work fine, at least now. Plus, you need to reopen Safari after updating it. Otherwise, the changed name on Safari's Preferences is not reflected.

Answer (score 2):

You can rename an extension quite easily. In the target, select the extension you need and go to **Info**. Change the **Bundle Display name**.

[image: ScreenShot]

Comment: Your answer could be improved by providing screenshots. As your answer is currently written, it's hard to understand the solution.

Answer (score 2):

You need to edit the "extension_name" key in the extension's `messages.json` file under `Resources/_locales.en/messages.json`

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a new scheme: click on the top-left 'Messenger Black' in your image and choose 'New scheme...' and put the new name in here. Save the scheme and this should then work okay.

Comment: It may a solution for legacy extensions, but it doesn't work for the new iOS 15 version of extensions.